# How do you include argument quotes in a script's code so that the user doesn't have to?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google-sheets script that requires the user to type `=getNotes("B19")` in a cell. But I want them to only have to type `=getNotes(B19)` without the quotes. Is this possible? I'm sure I've used scripts that don't require quotes before.

```
function getNotes(cell) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = sheet.getRange(cell);


 var results = range.getNotes();

 for (var i in results) {
   for (var j in results[i]) {
     Logger.log(results[i][j]);
   }
 }
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to access anything other than just the cell values via a custom function, then you will need to use the method of passing the cell reference as a string.

If the custom function is just using the values themselves, then you can pass a range, which will arrive in the script as a Javascript 2D array of values.

Comment: thanks adam. So in short, it's not possible correct?

Comment: Not possible for the case of retrieving notes, that's correct.